# Update other table based on a table value in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables named `Employee` and `Time`. I want to assign `OnTrack=y` if all the TaskList of employee code 1E are y.

I tried this and I am stuck

```
UPDATE Employee
SET OnTrack = 'y'
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.Code IN 
INNER JOIN (SELECT EmployeeCode FROM Time WHERE status = 'P') permanent
ON permanent.Employeecode = e.Code
AND permanent.Employeecode NOT IN
(SELECT EmployeeCode FROM Time t WHERE t.EmployeeCode=permanent.Employeecode and t.tasklist<>'y' )
```

My code is updating only one row. Can anyone please help?

Employee table :

```
Code    Name    Hours   OnTrack  
***********************************  
1E     SCOTT    32  
2E     LISA     32  
3E     MARK     32
```

Time table is

```
Code    Employeecode    Status  workingHours    TaskList  
********************************************************  
1A          1E             P      8               Y  
2A          1E             P      8               Y  
3A          1E             P      8               N  
4A          2E             T      8               Y  
5A          2E             T      0               Y  
6A          3E             P      8               Y
```

The result what expected is in employee table, OnTrack status should be updated if all its employee code has 'Y' in Time table as below:

```
Code    Name    Hours   OnTrack  

1E      SCOTT    24      N  
2E      LISA      12     Y  
3E      MARK      0      Y
```

Comment: i am not sure how the query even works.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @user3331421 please format your latest updates to make them readable cant make out much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created some table variables with test data. How about this:

```
DECLARE @Time TABLE (Code VARCHAR(2),Employeecode VARCHAR(2),Status CHAR(1), 
                     WorkingHours INT, TaskList CHAR(1))
INSERT @Time
VALUES  ('1A','1E','P',8,'Y'), 
        ('2A','1E','P',8,'Y'),  
        ('3A','1E','P',8,'N'), 
        ('4A','2E','T',8,'Y'),
        ('5A','2E','T',0,'Y'),
        ('6A','3E','P',8,'Y')
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (Code CHAR(2), Name VARCHAR(10), Hours INT, OnTrack CHAR(1))
INSERT @Employee
VALUES  ('1E','SCOTT',32,NULL),
        ('2E','LISA',32,NULL),  
        ('3E','MARK',32,NULL)

UPDATE e
SET e.OnTrack = t.TaskList
FROM @Employee e
JOIN (SELECT Employeecode, MIN(TaskList) TaskList
      FROM @Time
      GROUP BY Employeecode) t ON E.Code = T.Employeecode

SELECT *
FROM @Employee
```

Results:

```
Code    Name    Hours   OnTrack
1E      SCOTT   32      N
2E      LISA    32      Y
3E      MARK    32      Y
```

If you only want to update permanent employees, just add the `Status` to the subquery.

```
SELECT Employeecode, MIN(TaskList) TaskList
    FROM @Time
    WHERE Status = 'p'
    GROUP BY Employeecode
```

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you are using SQL Server) Try this select stmt first and if like the results use the update stmt down below. Its hard to write code without seeing the tables but just going by your explanation this should put you in the right direction.

```
select * 
FROM Employee e 
INNER JOIN TIME t1 ON t1.EmployeeCode  =   e.code 
INNER JOIN TIME t2 ON t2.EmployeeCode  <>  e.code 
WHERE t1.status    = 'P' 
AND   t2.tasklist <> 'y'
```

**Dont run this without trying the above select**

```
UPDATE Employee
SET OnTrack = 'y'
FROM Employee e 
INNER JOIN TIME t1 ON t1.EmployeeCode   = e.code 
INNER JOIN TIME t2 ON t2.EmployeeCode  <> e.code 
WHERE t1.status    = 'P' 
AND   t2.tasklist <> 'y'
```

Comment: Its good practice to use a 'begin transaction' when using sql,  that way you can always 'rollback transaction' and once your happy use the 'commit transaction'

Comment: @Standage SQLServer by default has Autocommit turned on. There are ways to turn that off and do what you suggest but thats beyond the scope of this thread. Good point nonetheless.

Comment: @user3331421 I suggest you show your tables and expected results by editing your main question.