# How to update column value in all rows that match with employee id in sql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying the following query

```
update employee
set e.Hours = tot.SumofWorkingHours
from employee e

inner join (select employeecode, sum(workingHours) as SumofWorkingHours
            from Time
            group by employeecode)tot
            on tot.employeecode=e.code)
```

I am struck here. I want to calculate sum of working hours corresponding to employee code and update the employee table with sum to the respective employee code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use a CTE

```
;WITH cte AS (
 SELECT EmployeeCode, SUM(WorkingHours) AS SumofWorkingHours
        FROM Time
        GROUP BY EmployeeCode)

UPDATE e
SET e.Hours = cte.SumofWorkingHours
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN cte ON e.Code = cte.EmployeeCode
```

I don't have any data to test the above query with, however if it doesn't work for you, provide some test data and we can give a more accurate solution.

Perhaps you need to use the alias `e` after the `UPDATE` statement. This is how I would write your original query (capitalization for OCD):

```
UPDATE e
SET e.Hours = tot.SumofWorkingHours
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN (SELECT EmployeeCode, SUM(WorkingHours) AS SumofWorkingHours
            FROM Time
            GROUP BY EmployeeCode) tot
            on tot.EmployeeCode = e.Code
```

Comment: Cant we have as a single statement?

Comment: I think that is a single statement.  first you establish the common table expression then underneath it you can use it.  I'm pretty sure it can all be treated as one statement.

Comment: @user3331421 This is another way of writing it. Looking at your original query, you have an extra parenthesis on the end. Is that a typo? See updated answer.

Comment: @user3331421 did you change your query to use the alias after the `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: can you answer for this also pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530191/update-other-table-based-on-a-table-value-in-sql?noredirect=1#comment64457842_38530191